# Convert a simple html file to scorm package

Tags: java, html, scorm1.2

I want to host my html asset into LMS, here LMS only accept and run the SCORM Package.

How can i convert an html file (exporting from my app using jasper report) to a scorm package?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For single pages, in fact the best approach I found was to do it mannually: based on: https://www.ispringsolutions.com/blog/how-to-convert-html-to-scorm to adapt it, just ignore the `res` folder and point to the index on: `<resource identifier="resource_1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="index.html">`

1. Download a SCORM example: https://21w98o3yqgi738kmv7xrf9lj-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/assets/golf_examples/PIFS/ContentPackagingSingleSCO_SCORM12.zip
2. extract it;
3. in `imsmanifest.xml` change the title to your title;
4. List all the resources that your HTML page includes;
5. Zip the course root folder (with the manifest file).

Answer (score -1):

On this page you will find software that you can use to create SCORM compatible packages. If you have created a simple project, you can unpack the resulting ZIP file and edit the content. Mostly you will find an index.html there. I know, that sounds a bit awkward at first.

https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Creating_SCORM_Content